# Cross-platform LAN messenger with chatlog server

Tags: cross-platform, chat, lan

I am looking for a LAN messenger with the following features

1. Cross-platform (Windows and Mac OS X at least)
2. Text chat of course
3. Conference chat
4. Text search in chat history. Unlike Spark, the search result should show the entire context of matching lines and not only the matching lines.
5. File transfer
6. Offline messages
7. A server to maintain a full history of all chats (only admin should see this and users should not be able to delete or disable chat history)
8. Should be either free or with one time payment

Comment: I just noticed that Spark is using XMPP standard. Can I use any XMPP based chat client and keep using Spark server with it?

Comment: I just tried using `Jitsi` client with Spark server. It works great and fulfils all the requirements as mentioned in OP, except one. It allows user to disable their chat history and delete the recorded history as well. Any help? Anyone?

Comment: A locally hosted IRC server perhaps ? They can be configured to log everything and there's plenty of free IRC clients.